# HTML/CSS SharePoint 2010

Tags: html, css, sharepoint-2010

I am using SharePoint 2010 and have a problem with inputting html codes.

I copy and paste the exact same code from another site page to create the same page again (then I modify etc.) However whenever the copied html is pasted and executed, the page ends up looking different. This is especially true for the top nav panels. They are all white/blank until I highlight them. The same is for any webpart that uses some CSS.

Is there a way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to write the HTML/CSS from scratch instead of copy pasting it. This is because
most probably you will end up overriding the default CSS which is provided by SharePoint instead of creating new classes yourself.

Have a look at:

http://sharepointexperience.com/csschart/csschart.html

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply, I was dreading that answer! But it looks like that is the best solution.